# Route workflow in IBM Maximo Anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Is there a way to route a record into workflow using Work execution or work approval app in Maximo anywhere ? I understand auto- initiate is not possible but I wanted to know whether there is a way to perform route.

Answer (score 0):

inside AnyWhere app we don't have route workflow.

Based on workorder.status you can create an escaltion, maximo side, and call an Action with value WFINITIATE as Application Action.

Answer (score 0):

What could also be possible is having a checkbox on anywhere. Put an automationscript on save or attribute launchPoint to check if the checkbox is ticked. Then use automation to initiate your workflow.

I believe the script looks something like this

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
MXServer.getMXServer().lookup("WORKFLOW").initiateWorkflow("[MYWF]",mbo);
```

or

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
wfs = MXServer.getMXServer().lookup("WORKFLOW")
wfs.initiateWorkflow('TESTWF', mbo)
```